# Every normal topological space is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

It is stated in Kolmogorov & Fomin's *Introductory Real Analysis* that every normal space is Hausdorff.  I cannot seem to find an explanation for this anywhere, and don't see why this is obviously true... since it is not necessarily the case in an arbitrary topological space that a singleton is closed.

Any help in understanding this would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must assume singletons are closed (equivalently, that the space is T$_1$).

Every indiscrete space is normal, but fails to be Hausdorff if it has more than one point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Are you saying that it is not the case that every normal space is Hausdorff, but rather, that every normal $T_1$-space is Hausdorff?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly right.

Comment: @Smath The notation $T_4$ for normal + $T_1$ spaces is used, and $T_3$ for regular + $T_1$ spaces. Then we have $T_4 \rightarrow T_3 \rightarrow T_2 \rightarrow T_1 \rightarrow T_0$ and none of the implications can be reversed. Also $T_5$ for "all subspaces are $T_4$", and $T_6$ for perfect (all closed sets are $G_\delta$) plus $T_4$. Then we can add $T_6 \rightarrow T_5 \rightarrow T_4$ etc as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is taken as part of the def'n of a normal space that it has the $T_1$ property, and it follows that a normal space is $T_2$. Engelking, in General Topology, calls a space in which disjoint closed subsets are completely separated a pseudo-normal space, as the $T_1$ property may fail. The simplest examples of a non-normal  pseudo-normal  space are (1) the topology $\{\phi, S\}$ on any $S$ with at least $2$ members, and (2) Sierpinski space : the topology $\{\phi,S,\{0\}\}$ on $S=\{0,1\}.$